# need to return two sets of data with two different where clauses

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that keeps track of transactions.

The table is setup as:

```
transactions:

id, account_id, budget_id, points, type
```

I need to return each budget_id's sum of points where type = 'allocation' and sum of points where type = 'issue'

I know how to do each, but not both in one query.

expected result set:

```
budget_id   allocated   issued
   434       200000      100
   242       100000      5020
   621       45000       3940
```

Comment: Subqueries in either the field list or a join to a subquery

Comment: E.g. to get you started `SELECT budget_id, A.all_sum AS allocated, I.iss_sum AS issued FROM transactions INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(points) AS all_sum FROM transactions WHERE type='Allocation') AS A INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(points) FROM transactions WHERE type='Issue') AS I`

Comment: @scrowler - will work, but you can use case to conditional sum if the grouping is the same.

Comment: Hi Brad. Did either of the below answers assist you? If so, please consider marking one of them as accepted.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT budget_id, 
       SUM(IF(type = 'allocation', points, 0)) AS allocated,
       SUM(IF(type = 'issue', points, 0)) AS issued
FROM transactions
GROUP BY budget_id
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    select budget_ID, 
     sum(case when type = 'allocated' then points else 0 end) as allocated,
     sum(case when type = 'issued' then points else 0 end) as issued
     ..rest of your query...
    group by budget_ID
```

Cases can be used to sum only when a certain criteria is met.