# How to aggregate the data without duplicates in Crosstab query

Tags: mysql

I have a sample table in MySQL like this:**(The actual table has much more races and schools)**

```
**race** |  **school**  | **name**
White    |     MIT      |   Jack 
White    |     MIT      |   Li
White    |     MIT      |   Don
White    |    Fordham   |   Dan
White    |    Fordham   |   Nan
White    |     NYU      |   Kate
Hispanic |     MIT      |   Jacob
Hispanic |    Fordham   |   Joe
Hispanic |    Fordham   |   Connie
Hispanic |     NYU      |   Sarah
Asian    |     MIT      |   Macro
Asian    |     MIT      |   Denise
Asian    |     MIT      |   Dennie
Asian    |     MIT      |   Sasa
Asian    |     Fordham  |   Mei
Asian    |     Fordham  |   Tian
Asian    |     Fordham  |   John
Asian    |     Fordham  |   Lala
Asian    |     NYU      |   Zed
Asian    |     NYU      |   Ann
Asian    |     NYU      |   Nancy
AmeIndian|     MIT      |   David
AmeIndian|     NYU      |   Lonnie
```

Firstly, I will aggregate the number of each race and order them descending. The query looks like this: (I know what to do for this part)

```
**race**    |   **Number**
 Asian      |      11
 White      |      6
 Hispanic   |      4
 AmeIndian  |      2
```

Finally, I want to get a crosstab query like this: (Just extract the top 3 in term of number of people in each race. Besides, the final query is ordered by the total number of people in each race)

```
**race**  |   **MIT**    |   **Fordham** |   **NYU**   |    **SUM**
Asian     |     4        |        4      |     3       |      11
White     |     3        |        2      |     1       |      6
Hispanic  |     1        |        2      |     1       |      4
```

I tried the code listed below. I cannot get the "SUM" column. And the number of people in each race under "MIT" and "Fordham" is the same and has duplicates.(refer to [need to return two sets of data with two different where clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254091/need-to-return-two-sets-of-data-with-two-different-where-clauses)) 
I think it is because I want to order by the total number of people in each race, and **order by the total number**. However, the order of number of people of each race is different among different schools.

```
SELECT race,
   COUNT(IF(school="MIT",race,0)) as MIT,
   COUNT(IF(school="Fordham",race,0)) as Fordham
FROM table_name
GROUP by race
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `COUNT()` it should be `SUM()`.

```
SELECT race,
      SUM(IF(school='MIT',1,0)) as MIT,
      SUM(IF(school='Fordham',1,0)) as Fordham,
      SUM(IF(school='NYU',1,0)) AS NYU,
      (SUM(IF(school='MIT',1,0))+SUM(IF(school='Fordham',1,0))+SUM(IF(school='NYU',1,0))) AS Total_Sum
FROM table_name
GROUP by race
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. It is helpful. It is near. But the Count(*) as Total_Sum will sum everything on that race including AmeIndian.However, if I just want to sum the number of people in term of top 3 or the number of school I want to show?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic sql query to achieve this.

**QUERY**

```
set @query = null;
select
group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'count(case when school = ''',
      school, ''' then school end) as ',school
    )
  ) into @query
from your_table_name ;

set @query = concat('select race, ', @query, ',count(*) as `SUM` from your_table_name 
                  group by race order by count(*) desc limit 3
');

prepare stmt from @query;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+----------+-----+---------+-----+-----+
|     race | MIT | Fordham | NYU | SUM |
+----------+-----+---------+-----+-----+
|    Asian |   4 |       4 |   3 |  11 |
|    White |   3 |       2 |   1 |   6 |
| Hispanic |   1 |       2 |   1 |   4 |
+----------+-----+---------+-----+-----+
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/377d8/3)

Answer (score 0):

firstly:

```
select * from 
(
    select count(*) as count,race from table1 group by race
) as data
order by data.count desc;
```

finally

```
select data.* from (
SELECT race,
      SUM(IF(school='MIT',1,0)) as MIT,
      SUM(IF(school='Fordham',1,0)) as Fordham,
      SUM(IF(school='NYU',1,0)) AS NYU,
      COUNT(*) AS total_Sum
FROM table1
GROUP by race ) as data
order by data.total_Sum desc;
```