# MYSQL Unknown Column in Query

Tags: mysql

I am looking to fetch sum of transactions grouping them by item ID. I am able to get desired result fron below query in Oracle DB but the same does not work in MYSQL.

Below error is what I am getting:

> Unknown column 'tran.itemid' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT tran.itemid, 
    (SELECT SUM(tranitm.quandity) 
        FROM transactions_item tranitm 
        JOIN transactions tr  
            ON(tr.id  = tranitm.transid and tranitm.itemid = tran.itemid) 
        where TR.TRANSTYPE = 1) Purchases, 
    (SELECT SUM(tranitm.quandity) 
        FROM transactions_item tranitm 
        JOIN transactions tr 
            ON(tr.id = tranitm.transid and tranitm.itemid = tran.itemid) 
        where TR.TRANSTYPE = 2 ) Sales, 
    (SELECT SUM(tranitm.quandity) 
        FROM transactions_item tranitm 
        JOIN transactions tr 
            ON(tr.id = tranitm.transid and tranitm.itemid = tran.itemid) 
        where TR.TRANSTYPE = 3 ) PurchasesRtn, 
    (SELECT SUM(tranitm.quandity) 
        FROM transactions_item tranitm 
        JOIN  transactions tr 
            ON(tr.id = tranitm.transid and tranitm.itemid = tran.itemid)
        where TR.TRANSTYPE = 4) SalesRtn 
FROM transactions_item tran 
GROUP BY tran.itemid
```

Schema :

```
CREATE TABLE transactions
( id INT, transtype INT,fromledger INT,
 ledgerid INT,agentid INT, quandity FLOAT,rate FLOAT);

CREATE TABLE transactions_item
 (transid INT, itemid INT,quandity FLOAT,rate FLOAT);

INsert into transactions (id, transtype, fromledger, ledgerid, agentid, 
 quandity, rate) values (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 100, 1000);
INsert into transactions (id, transtype, fromledger, ledgerid, agentid, 
 quandity, rate) values (2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1200);
INsert into transactions (id, transtype, fromledger, ledgerid, agentid, 
 quandity, rate) values (3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 50, 1500);
INsert into transactions (id, transtype, fromledger, ledgerid, agentid, 
 quandity, rate) values (4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 120, 1300);
INsert into transactions (id, transtype, fromledger, ledgerid, agentid, 
 quandity, rate) values (5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1100);
INsert into transactions (id, transtype, fromledger, ledgerid, agentid, 
 quandity, rate) values (6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 12, 1400);
INsert into transactions (id, transtype, fromledger, ledgerid, agentid, 
 quandity, rate) values (7, 3, 1, 1, 1, 130, 1550);
INsert into transactions (id, transtype, fromledger, ledgerid, agentid, 
 quandity, rate) values (8, 4, 1, 1, 1, 110, 1700);

INsert into transactions_item (transid, itemid,quandity,rate) values (1, 1, 100, 1000);
INsert into transactions_item (transid, itemid,quandity,rate) values (2, 1, 10, 1200);
INsert into transactions_item (transid, itemid,quandity,rate) values (3, 1, 50, 1500);
INsert into transactions_item (transid, itemid,quandity,rate) values (4, 1, 120, 1300);
INsert into transactions_item (transid, itemid,quandity,rate) values (5, 1, 10, 1100);
INsert into transactions_item (transid, itemid,quandity,rate) values (6, 1, 12, 1400);
INsert into transactions_item (transid, itemid,quandity,rate) values (7, 1, 130, 1550);
INsert into transactions_item (transid, itemid,quandity,rate) values (8, 1, 110, 1700);
INsert into transactions_item (transid, itemid,quandity,rate) values (1, 2, 100, 1000);
INsert into transactions_item (transid, itemid,quandity,rate) values (2, 2, 10, 1200);
INsert into transactions_item (transid, itemid,quandity,rate) values (3, 2, 50, 1500);
INsert into transactions_item (transid, itemid,quandity,rate) values (4, 2, 120, 1300);
INsert into transactions_item (transid, itemid,quandity,rate) values (5, 2, 10, 1100);
INsert into transactions_item (transid, itemid,quandity,rate) values (6, 2, 12, 1400);
INsert into transactions_item (transid, itemid,quandity,rate) values (7, 2, 130, 1550);
INsert into transactions_item (transid, itemid,quandity,rate) values (8, 2, 110, 1700);
```

Comment: Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Why do you have `quandity` and `rate` in both tables?

Comment: transactions is master table.....transactions_item is child............quandity and rate in master is the sum of all the entries in child table. Child table can have multiple item entires for same transaction id.

Answer (score 1):

The `ON` clauses in the subqueries should be used to relate the tables being joined. Conditions that aren't part of the join should be in `WHERE`.

But there's a better way to do this than all those correlated subqueries.

```
SELECT tran.itemid,
        SUM(IF(tr.transtype = 1, tran.quandity, 0)) AS Purchases,
        SUM(IF(tr.transtype = 2, tran.quandity, 0)) AS Sales,
        SUM(IF(tr.transtype = 3, tran.quandity, 0)) AS PurchasesRtn,
        SUM(IF(tr.transtype = 4, tran.quandity, 0)) AS SalesRtn
FROM transactions_item AS tran
JOIN transactions AS tr ON tran.transid = tr.id
GROUP BY tran.itemid
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57bbe5/2)

See [need to return two sets of data with two different where clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254091/need-to-return-two-sets-of-data-with-two-different-where-clauses/25254168#25254168)

Comment: Thank you for the above. But I am getting same result for all the items with the above.

Comment: Getting 1084 for all Purchases, Sales..........and for both items (1 & 2)

Comment: Forgot the `ON` clause

Comment: I think it is self joining the table

Comment: I changed the above query to: SELECT tran.itemid,
        SUM(IF(tr.transtype = 1, tran.quandity, 0)) AS Purchases,
        SUM(IF(tr.transtype = 2, tran.quandity, 0)) AS Sales,
        SUM(IF(tr.transtype = 3, tran.quandity, 0)) AS PurchasesRtn,
        SUM(IF(tr.transtype = 4, tran.quandity, 0)) AS SalesRtn
FROM transactions_item AS tran
JOIN transactions AS tr ON tr.id = tran.transid
GROUP BY tran.itemid    ......................................now getting the correct result but it is repeating for both the item id's(1&2)

Comment: SELECT tran.itemid,
        SUM(IF(tr.transtype = 1, tran.quandity, 0)) AS Purchases,
        SUM(IF(tr.transtype = 2, tran.quandity, 0)) AS Sales,
        SUM(IF(tr.transtype = 3, tran.quandity, 0)) AS PurchasesRtn,
        SUM(IF(tr.transtype = 4, tran.quandity, 0)) AS SalesRtn
FROM transactions_item AS tran
JOIN transactions AS tr ON tr.id = tran.transid
GROUP BY tran.itemid

Comment: now the only issue with above query is getting the correct count for individual items and I think this needs a self join.....not sure though

Comment: I'm getting the same totals for both items, but that's because your data has the same quandities for both.

Comment: Like `(1, 1, 100, 1000)` and `(1, 2, 100, 1000)`

Comment: Thank you Barmar......thats great help........sorry to ask but there is another addition to be made to the above response. I need to change the itemid to itemname and that exists in another table for which below is the schema:

Comment: CREATE TABLE item_dtl( id INT, name VARCHAR(50));

Comment: I tried the below query to get itemname but getting same result for both the items

Comment: SELECT itm.name as itemname,
        SUM(IF(tr.transtype = 1, tran.quandity, 0)) AS Purchases,
        SUM(IF(tr.transtype = 2, tran.quandity, 0)) AS Sales,
        SUM(IF(tr.transtype = 3, tran.quandity, 0)) AS PurchasesRtn,
        SUM(IF(tr.transtype = 4, tran.quandity, 0)) AS SalesRtn
FROM transactions_item AS tran
JOIN item_dtl AS itm ON itm.id = tran.itemid
JOIN transactions AS tr ON tr.id = tran.transid
GROUP BY itemname

Comment: It works for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/254a46/2 Maybe you forgot to update the input data for this test.