# How to group database records by field using another field for calculating aggregate values in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table with fields 'name', 'type' and 'amount', for example

```
|------------|-------|----------|
| name       | type  | amount   |
|------------|-------|----------|
| Name_1     | 1     | 100      |
|------------|-------|----------|
| Name_1     | 2     | 200      |
|------------|-------|----------|
| Name_2     | 1     | 300      |
|------------|-------|----------|
| Name_1     | 1     | 400      |
|------------|-------|----------|
```

And I need to receive a result

```
|------------|---------------------------|--------------------------|
| name       | sum(amount) of type 1     | sum(amount) of type 2    |
|------------|---------------------------|--------------------------|
| Name_1     | 500 (as 100 + 400)        | 200                      |
|------------|---------------------------|--------------------------|
| Name_2     | 300                       | 0                        |
|------------|---------------------------|--------------------------|
```

How can I do it with Laravel? Or with MySQL?

PS. As @Barmar say, the decision of 
a question is already found ([need to return two sets of data with two different where clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254091/need-to-return-two-sets-of-data-with-two-different-where-clauses)). But this is fully MySQL approach, also interest Laravel Eloquent decision.

Comment: What you want is pivotting your data.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Sorry, I don't understand what do you want to tell me.

Comment: Converting rows into columns is a process called pivot..