# mysql select multiple avg columns using where in condition and join query

Tags: mysql

how to use where in condition with this query? like,  WHERE institutions.instituteId IN ("1","2","4","15").

```
SELECT (SELECT avg(rating_score.score) FROM reviews INNER JOIN rating_score ON  reviews.reviewsId=rating_score.reviewsId WHERE reviews.instituteId='13' AND ratingItemId='1') as 'Acadamics', 
(SELECT avg(rating_score.score) FROM reviews INNER JOIN rating_score ON reviews.reviewsId=rating_score.reviewsId WHERE reviews.instituteId='13' AND ratingItemId='2') as 'Area_of_study',
(SELECT avg(rating_score.score) FROM reviews INNER JOIN rating_score ON reviews.reviewsId=rating_score.reviewsId WHERE reviews.instituteId='13' AND ratingItemId='3') as 'Campus_Facilities', 
(SELECT avg(rating_score.score) FROM reviews INNER JOIN rating_score ON reviews.reviewsId=rating_score.reviewsId WHERE reviews.instituteId='13' AND ratingItemId='4') as 'Acommadatoin',
(SELECT avg(rating_score.score) FROM reviews INNER JOIN rating_score ON reviews.reviewsId=rating_score.reviewsId WHERE reviews.instituteId='13' AND ratingItemId='5') as 'Sports_Facilities',
institutions.instituteId, institutions.instituteName, institutions.location, countries.countryName, institutions.siteAddress, institutions.overallRatings FROM institutions INNER JOIN countries ON institutions.countryId=countries.countryId 
WHERE institutions.instituteId='13'
```

Comment: See the linked question, just replace `SUM` with `AVG`.

Comment: but it returns sum of fileds.

Comment: i want to select using where in condition.

Comment: If you change `SUM()` to `AVG()` it will return the average instead of sum. What's the problem you're having with the where condition?

Comment: i want average score of institutions but here only one instituteid so it returns one result.

Comment: Change to `WHERE institutions.instituteId IN ("1","2","4","15")` and use the method in the linked question and it will work.

Comment: Also use `GROUP BY instituteId` to get a separate result for each institute.

Comment: Isn't that shown in the linked question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to the solutions in [need to return two sets of data with two different where clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254091/need-to-return-two-sets-of-data-with-two-different-where-clauses?noredirect=1&lq=1) but uses `AVG` instead of `SUM`. The main difference is that you don't use `ELSE 0` in the `CASE`, because you don't want to average `0` for all the rows with a different `raingItemId`. `AVG()` will just ignore those null rows.

```
SELECT 
    AVG(CASE WHEN ratingItemId='1' THEN rs.score END) AS Academics,
    AVG(CASE WHEN ratingItemId='2' THEN rs.score END) AS Area_of_study,
    AVG(CASE WHEN ratingItemId='3' THEN rs.score END) AS Campus_Facilities,
    AVG(CASE WHEN ratingItemId='4' THEN rs.score END) AS Acommadatoin,
    AVG(CASE WHEN ratingItemId='5' THEN rs.score END) AS Sports_Facilities,
    i.instituteName, i.location, c.countryName, i.siteAddress, i.overallRatings
FROM institutions AS i
INNER JOIN countries AS c ON i.countryId=c.countryId
LEFT JOIN reviews AS r ON r.instituteId = i.instituteId
LEFT JOIN rating_score AS rs ON rs.reviewsId = r.reviewsId
WHERE i.instituteId IN (1, 2, 4, 15)
GROUP BY i.instituteId
```