# Mysql] Find the first and the last date of event a user joined with different roles

Tags: mysql

I have three tables and I need to find the very first date and the very last(recent) date of an event users has joined as a host and a guest. In other words, the returned data should look like the following:

(please note that it's the very first and the very last(recent) date of all events a user has attended)

```
+----+-----+---------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| id |name |  Event  | First date as a host | Recent date as a host | First date as a guest | Recentdate as a guest |
+----+-----+---------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | Teo | Dance   | 2018-01-01           | 2017-01-01            | 2016-02-01            | 2017-09-09            |
|  2 | Jac | Karaoke | 2018-03-02           | 2018-01-01            | 2016-07-07            | 2017-01-06            |
|  3 | Lay | Boxing  | 2017-09-09           | 2018-07-07            | 2017-01-01            | 2018-02-02            |
+----+-----+---------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

---

Tables

---

**Users**
id
 
name

**Event**
id
 
name
starts_at

**Event_Users**
id
 
user_id
event_id
role

I tried to follow an instruction here[https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/4-ways-to-join-only-the-first-row-in-sql]... but when it comes to writing a query that retrieves 4 different first rows(min/max), i always end up with a super messy query that doesn't even work...

What would be the easiest solution for this kind of tricky requirement?

Thanks

Comment: Post your "super messy query that doesn't work" in your question.  There's likely no non-messy way to do this, so your attempt may not be far off base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows the same pattern as [need to return two sets of data with two different where clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254091/need-to-return-two-sets-of-data-with-two-different-where-clauses/25254168#25254168) except it uses `MIN` and `MAX` instead of `SUM`.

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, e.name AS Event,
    MIN(IF(eu.role = 'host', e.starts_at, NULL)) AS First_date_as_host,
    MAX(IF(eu.role = 'host', e.starts_at, NULL)) AS Recent_date_as_host,
    MIN(IF(eu.role = 'guest', e.starts_at, NULL)) AS First_date_as_guest,
    MAX(IF(eu.role = 'guest', e.starts_at, NULL)) AS Recent_date_as_guest
FROM users AS u
JOIN event_users AS eu ON eu.user_id = u.id
JOIN events AS e ON e.id = eu.event_id
GROUP BY u.id, e.id
```