# Case Expression returning NULL in MYSQL when there are records

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has product_id column which can be any idea from 1-28.  There are two types of products.  Products that have id in 25,27,28 and products with other ids.

```
select  case when product_id in (25,27,28) then sum(actual_weight) end as Whole_Chickens_weight, 
        case when product_id in (25, 27, 28) then count(*) end as count_of_chickens,      
        case when product_id not in (25, 27, 28) then sum(boxed_weight) end as parts_weight,   
        case when product_id not in (25, 27, 28) then count(*) end as count_of_parts    
     from item_detail where Date(packaged_time) = Date("2022-11-09") ;
```

the query always returns the product in clause but not for the parts clauses.

```
 case when product_id not in (25, 27, 28) then sum(boxed_weight) end as parts_weight,
```

always return null.

Comment: can you add a ddl of data or a fiddle link to make a [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition should be inside the aggregation function:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN product_id IN (25, 27, 28) THEN actual_weight END) AS Whole_Chickens_weight
```

and similar for the other cases.

See [need to return two sets of data with two different where clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254091/need-to-return-two-sets-of-data-with-two-different-where-clauses/25254168#25254168)

Comment: @Mohamed if you don't do this, your `case` is going to check just *one* product_id from an arbitrary row to decide which sum to return.  the enabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql_mode (which is the default in newer versions) will prevent you from making this kind of error.  By putting the case inside the sum, you cause it to check the product_id for each row to determine if the row contributes to that sum.