# MySQL - creating subqueries instead of using joins

Tags: mysql

I'm just starting out with MySQL and I'm creating a database for a project for an online course based on support hours delivered to schools by a local authority. Each type of support has a number of hours attached to it, recorded as part of a whole day (e.g. a staff meeting = 0.25 days). Number of hours attached to each type of support is recorded in a table (support_type) and then there is a separate table detailing number of times support is given to each school (support_record) which can be updated as more support is delviered.

For context, this is the table support_type referenced in the view below.

| support_id | support_type | support_days | billing_cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| smt | staff meeting | 0.25 | 125 |
| acs | additional cluster session | 0.5 | 250 |
| hds | half day support | 0.5 | 250 |
| rau | reading audit | 0.75 | 375 |
| wau | writing audit | 0.75 | 375 |
| fds | full day support | 1 | 500 |

To calculate the number of hours each school has had, I've created a view for each support_id. Now I'm trying to create a separate view that shows the total number of hours delivered to each school.

These queries and views all work but any suggestions for simplifiying what I've done is greatly appreciated! I'm sure I should be able to use subqueries instaed of joins but I'm not really sure how.

```
CREATE VIEW staff_meetings
AS
SELECT sr.school_id, sr.smt, SUM(sr.smt*st.support_days) AS smt_support_total
FROM support_record sr
CROSS JOIN support_type st 
WHERE st.support_id = 'smt'
GROUP BY sr.school_id;
```

This worked to create a view to pull the data from for my next table - there are six of these  views (one for each support_id) that I'm using to create the next view.

| school_id | smt | smt_support_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S01 | 1 | 0.25 |
| S02 | 1 | 0.25 |
| S03 | 2 | 0.5 |
| S04 | 3 | 0.75 |
| S05 | 0 | 0 |

View to give an overall total of support delivered:

```
SELECT sr.school_id, 
  rau.rau_support_total, 
  wau.wau_support_total, 
  smt.smt_support_total, 
  hds.hds_support_total, 
  fds.fds_support_total, 
  acs.acs_support_total, 
  SUM(rau.rau_support_total
    + wau.wau_support_total
    + smt.smt_support_total
    + hds.hds_support_total
    + fds.fds_support_total
    + acs.acs_support_total) AS support_days_total
FROM support_record sr
LEFT JOIN reading_audit_hours rau
ON sr.school_id = rau.school_id
LEFT JOIN writing_audit_hours wau
ON sr.school_id = wau.school_id
LEFT JOIN staff_meetings smt
ON sr.school_id = smt.school_id
LEFT JOIN half_day_support hds
ON sr.school_id = hds.school_id
LEFT JOIN full_day_support fds
ON sr.school_id = fds.school_id
LEFT JOIN additional_cluster_sessions acs
ON sr.school_id = acs.school_id
GROUP BY school_id;
```

Like I said, it works but feels very long winded. Really appreciate any advice as I'm only starting out.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use subqueries instead of joins? Joins are better than subqueries in most cases. More flexible, more expressive, better for performance, etc.

Comment: You seem to be going about this wrong. First you're writing a view for each type, then you're combining them back into a single query by joining with each view. Just join with the original table in the first place. If you want to get them all into a single row for each school, use per-type sums. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254091/need-to-return-two-sets-of-data-with-two-different-where-clauses/25254168#25254168

Comment: For the project I’m required to use subqueries which is why I’m asking

Comment: 90% of the time views just complicate things.  Avoid them unless you know one would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that requires just one join, not numerous joins:

```
select sr.school_id,
  sum(sr.smt * case st.support_id when 'rau' then st.support_days else 0 end) as rau_support_total,
  sum(sr.smt * case st.support_id when 'wau' then st.support_days else 0 end) as wau_support_total,
  sum(sr.smt * case st.support_id when 'smt' then st.support_days else 0 end) as smt_support_total,
  sum(sr.smt * case st.support_id when 'hds' then st.support_days else 0 end) as hds_support_total,
  sum(sr.smt * case st.support_id when 'fds' then st.support_days else 0 end) as fds_support_total,
  sum(sr.smt * st.support_days) as support_days_total
from support_record as sr
cross join support_type as st
group by sr.school_id
order by sr.school_id;
```

Here's a solution that works with no joins:

```
select sr.school_id,
  sum(sr.smt * (select support_days from support_type where support_id = 'rau')) as rau_support_total,
  sum(sr.smt * (select support_days from support_type where support_id = 'wau')) as wau_support_total,
  sum(sr.smt * (select support_days from support_type where support_id = 'smt')) as smt_support_total,
  sum(sr.smt * (select support_days from support_type where support_id = 'hds')) as hds_support_total,
  sum(sr.smt * (select support_days from support_type where support_id = 'fds')) as fds_support_total,
  sum(sr.smt * (select sum(support_days) from support_type)) as support_days_total
from support_record as sr
group by sr.school_id
order by sr.school_id;
```

Output for both:

```
+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| school_id | rau_support_total | wau_support_total | smt_support_total | hds_support_total | fds_support_total | support_days_total |
+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| S01       |              0.75 |              0.75 |              0.25 |              0.50 |              1.00 |               3.75 |
| S02       |              0.75 |              0.75 |              0.25 |              0.50 |              1.00 |               3.75 |
| S03       |              1.50 |              1.50 |              0.50 |              1.00 |              2.00 |               7.50 |
| S04       |              2.25 |              2.25 |              0.75 |              1.50 |              3.00 |              11.25 |
| S05       |              0.00 |              0.00 |              0.00 |              0.00 |              0.00 |               0.00 |
+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/BRByoRWp