Selecting from 1 table and put the result into 2 column
I have to select from a table and put into a 2 column result.
This is the table I have,
MAILTABLE:



MAIL_KIND
CODE
PRICE




PRIORITY
MAILCOST
20


REGULAR
MAILCOST
10



So from trying out the exercise above,
I have the following SQL statement:
select 
  (select PRICE from MAILTABLE where CODE = 'MAILCOST' AND MAIL_KIND = 'PRIORITY') as PM,
  (select PRICE from MAILTABLE where CODE = 'MAILCOST' AND MAIL_KIND = 'REGULAR') as RM
from MAILTABLE

But I'm getting a bunch of result which is not what I want is to differentiate the PRIORITY mail cost and the REGULAR mail cost like below:



PM
RM




20
10



How do I select from 1 table and put into a 2 column result?

You don't need the last FROM MAILTABLE. That will produce a row in the result for every row in the original table.

Sorry, I have understood nothing. Could you please  provide the desired output for your MAILTABLE

Leave out FROM MAILTABLE at the end. That causes it to return the values of the subqueries for each row in the original table.
Use FROM DUAL as a dummy table when you don't need a specific table in the main query.
select (select PRICE from MAILTABLE where CODE = 'MAILCOST' AND MAIL_KIND = 'PRIORITY') as PM,
       (select PRICE from MAILTABLE where CODE = 'MAILCOST' AND MAIL_KIND = 'REGULAR') as RM
FROM DUAL


What if I add another row ('REGULAR','MAILCOST',30); ? https://dbfiddle.uk/8hlZTqdr

What should the result be if you do that?

Just saying I am not the OP. IMO this seems a task for conditional aggregation, still it is for the OP to clarify

I see that you made that assumption in your answer. I thought this was more of a simple pivot.

I tried this but it's looking for a 'FROM' keyword

I can't reproduce that. Are you sure you're using MySQL, not some other DBMS? Anyway, add FROM DUAL if you need a dummy table.

my mistake, i thought i am using mysql. I am using plsql. thank you so much!

Oracle is the database, PL/SQL is used to embed SQL statements into a programming language like C.

Note you don't need the DUAL table in Oracle 23c.

@JonasMetzler Also not in MySQL (as the question was originally tagged). But there no harm, and then it's compatible with other versions and other databases.

Based on your desired output this seems a task for conditional aggregation
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CODE = 'MAILCOST' AND MAIL_KIND = 'PRIORITY' THEN PRICE END) AS PM,
        SUM(CASE WHEN CODE = 'MAILCOST' AND MAIL_KIND = 'REGULAR' THEN PRICE END) AS RM
FROM MAILTABLE;

See example

If this is the solution, the question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254091/need-to-return-two-sets-of-data-with-two-different-where-clauses/25254168#25254168

what if I only have 2 fixed rows in the maintable and don't want to do 'SUM'? Do I just remove it?

@HannahReyes yes, you can remove it, it is excess. If you leave it will make no difference

@HannahReyes This is performing a pivot using conditional aggregation which means that you need to use an aggregation function (i.e. MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG, etc.). It doesn't matter which one you use but if you want to combine multiple input rows into a single output row using this technique then you need to use one of them.

Another solution would be:
SELECT PR.PRICE as PR, RM.PRICE as RM
FROM MAILTABLE PR
INNER JOIN MAILTABLE RM ON RM.CODE= 'MAILCOST' and RM.MAIL_KIND='REGULAR'
WHERE PR.CODE='MAILCOST' AND PR.MAIL_KIND='PRIORITY'

see: DBFIDDLE
